# Why OS X never ejects drives before shutdown or suspend mode?

Tags: usb, external-disk, macos, firewire

I have this problem since Lion if I am not mistaken. If a leave an USB or even my FireWire (backup) HDD connected OS X does not eject the drives before shutting down or entering suspend mode.
Why?
I am using now macOS Sierra and the problem persist.
It bothered me for a while till I started unmounting the drives after using them.
But I need to keep my FireWire HDD connected to use Time Machine's backup.
How can I solve that since even with fresh installs of Mac OS X it happens?

Comment: Can you explain how you know the drives are not being unmounted?

Comment: The "eject" process is to make sure that all delayed writes have been performed. The process of shutting down the computer means they are effectively ejected. If by "suspend" you mean "sleep," I'm not sure what process is followed, but I wouldn't recommend just randomly unplugging things from a sleeping computer in general.

Answer (score -1):

**I will share a why it is good to have it as is and a way around it if you are determined.**

> When you put the Mac to sleep, it will try and also put the external
>   drive to sleep, thus parking its heads and turning off the drives. It
>   won't eject it, however, so you can use it as soon as you wake your
>   Mac again without having to mount it.
>
> The benefit is that you don't have to worry about mounting it, as in
>   most cases this would involve turning the drive off and on again,
>   reconnecting the plug, or using diskutil from a Terminal—quite time
>   consuming. Since I use my drive for Time Machine, I don't want to have
>   to think about connecting it every time I wake my Mac.
>
> The only downside I see is that you could accidentally plug the drive
>   out. In that case, the Mac will wake up, and show you the error about
>   a drive being disconnected without properly ejecting it. Since all
>   data is written to the drive before going to sleep, this shouldn't
>   cause any data loss though.
>
> All in all, it's much more comfortable to just keep the drive mounted.

**If you want to unmount the drives before sleep:**

- You can use the automator > files/folders > eject disk > tell it when
  to eject.
- Use terminal to unmount all drives before sleep. < not comfortable giving you the code as it can vary.

Comment: I forgot to add that very OS X gives a message when the disk is not correctly unmounted

Comment: All computers should give an alert message regarding non safe methods of unmounting like unplugging before unmounting. Unless you are saying it gives a warning when it goes to sleep and the drive was never unplugged?

Comment: @tenshimsm you should give this a read. http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/67251/is-it-necessary-to-eject-external-drives-before-logging-out-restarting-or-shut